# In SharePoint Framework Extension (Application Customizer), are there any other placeholders that can be used aside from the header and footer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, reactjs, applicationcustomizers

We are trying to add a drop-down control in the command bar of a page or beside the share button on a SharePoint Online site.

[image]

May we know if there is a specific placeholder we can use to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not at this moment, however it is in the works according to this uservoice:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/19536022-extensions-application-customizer-additional-pl

In addition to the Header and Footer page placeholders you have the ability to customize list menus: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api

But this will not be applicable in a page view context...